# Ignore key if empty value

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I'm creating a mongoose entry, and this is my schema:

```
const OrdersSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    user: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "Users",
        required: true,
    },
    currency: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    country: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    rate: {
        type: Number,
        required: true,
    },
    amount: {
        type: Number,
        required: true,
    },
    coupon: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "Coupons",
    },

    subtotal: {
        type: Number,
        required: true,
    },
    total: {
        type: Number,
        required: true,
    },
    recipient: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        required: true,
    },
    status: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        default: "On-hold",
    },
    payment: {
        type: Object,
        required: true,
    },
    shortId: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    createdAt: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now,
        required: true,
    },
});
```

Coupon is optional. The code to create a new order is:

```
const order = await Orders.create({
            user: req.id,
            currency: body.selectedCountry,
            country: body.selectedCountry,
            rate: rate.rates[body.selectedCountry],
            amount: body.amount,
            coupon: body.coupon.code,
            subtotal: body.subtotal,
            total: body.total,
            recipient: body.recipient,
            payment: body.paymentData,
            shortId: shortid.generate(),
        });
```

However, when coupon is an empty string I get a `MongooseError [CastError]: Cast to ObjectID failed for value "" at path "coupon"`

I need to remove this key and value from the object creation, when creating the order.

How can I remove this key if coupon code is empty?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is you are trying to fit an empty string value in the data-type objectID.

A possible solution to this is to use below condition in your code:

```
coupon: body.coupon.code ? body.coupon.code : null
```

This will set coupon to null in case body.coupon.code is "".